# Skype with both system and microphone audio in El Capitan

Tags: audio, microphone, skype, soundflower

I'm trying to use Skype for screen sharing with simultaneous audio from my microphone and the Mac system (for example a video or a game).

Using Soundflower, and in the Audio Midi Setup an Aggregate Device for input and a Multi-Output Device for output I've been able to get either Mac system audio or microphone (voice), but not both.

In some settings, both seem to be input, but only the system audio is output, or just a very quick bit of voice can be heard before cutting out.

I'm stumped...

Here are the Skype audio settings:
[image: skype audio settings]

And here are the Mac settings:

First, Audio Midi Setup

[image]
[image]

And Sound from System Preferences
[image]
[image]

I have found some videos on YouTube that discuss this, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eo_o6FnmSrs) which I've followed, but still no luck.

Thanks. Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: OK, for starters [that is, if Soundflower even works properly under El Capitan - I had to uninstall it years ago after kernel panics] you need to be routing inputs from the game & mic to Soundflower, then Soundflower to Skype. For outputs just use 'built-in output' as normal. For a whole lot simpler & more robust setup, use [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) but that's 50 bucks.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm thinking (and reading) that Soundflower doesn't work in El Capitan. Jack also might not work... I'm trying something called iShowU Audio, but that might not do it either. Starting to regret having upgraded to El Capitan... But your comment is helpful.

Comment: Sound flower started to get crashy at about Mavericks,& hasn't really been supported in years, it's not really El Cap's fault :) There's a v2 beta at https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases but even that's a year old now. I haven't tried it personally.

Answer (score 1):

I have just done this - for skype recording and it works:
My settings are almost identical to yours except: -

in skype I have the microphone as my mic - not as the aggregate device.

I have also added my headphones (!) as part of the multi output device. ie headphones + built in + soundflower (2 chan)

I can now record the entire skype video + audio + the mic input from my end using Quicktime screen recording with the mic input set to the aggregate device...

nb - no "flowerbed" used, no "line-in" used